# Should I use strong pointers when I transfer a model from ViewController to ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Suppose I have an app that displays pictures of "Pizzas". Let's say the model of my app is simply an array that contains 9 UIImages of different pizzas.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *myPizzas;
```

The array is created in the first view controller called `FirstViewController`.  This view controller also displays the first 3 pizza images.  When the user taps a button on screen, this pizza array is transferred to a second view controller (`SecondViewController`) which displays the next 3 pizzas.  Finally, when the user taps a final button on screen the array is transferred to a final view controller (`ThirdViewController`) which displays the last three pizzas.

Suppose this is all the app does and that each time a new view controller is segued to, it is pushed onto a navigation controller stack.

My question is, should each of the view controllers have a `strong` reference to the array or should just the first one have the `strong` reference and the last two view controllers have a `weak` reference? And most importantly, WHY is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * myPizzas;
```

You read that right -- *copy*. If the type is copyable, `copy` is (nearly) always the right choice -- particularly when the type is immutable.

If the type were a type which does not adopt `NSCopying`, then you would choose `strong`.

There's no benefit or need to use a `weak` reference. Weak references complicate the semantics and ownership of your program's objects. Using weak here is completely unnecessary. Chances are good that a weak pointer would only result in increased maintenance over time. So, you can just avoid the complication by using strong references.

Comment: The only valid option for `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSSet` properties should be `copy`. There's just no excuse to use anything else for collection classes unless your own object is gonna wind up in that collection.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan exactly (+1) -- those classes you mentioned, and several others. for those that find this odd: the reason is semantics, and that copying early *prevents* copying (in many cases) when you are dealing with mutable parameters. the `copy` implementation of a well designed immutable class can often be implemented as: `return [self retain];`

Comment: Nearly +1 but it was stated in the question that the model is an array only for the purposes of the is discussion.  In reality it may be an object without copy semantics.

Comment: Changed my mind, actually +1 since you also give the correct answer.

Comment: @JeremyP thanks - i'll add a note for types which are not copyable…

Answer (score 1):

Practically , dasblinkenlight is correct. As long as you have one strong reference your array will persist. A singleton will also work - but I try and avoid using them just to pass data around.

The most common pattern you'll see, however, is to have properties as a strong references (although in the case of your particular example an NSArray should be copy).

A strong reference, because it retains encapsulation. Your controllers are not dependent on being in an environment where some other object is responsible for maintaining a strong reference.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter, you can go either way. You need to have at least one strong reference, and both choices provide it. If you use strong references, the number of retain/release messages will increase, but the mechanics of this is hidden from you, so you would not notice anything.

There is an alternative choice that does not involve having references at all: make your model with its `myPizzas` array a singleton, and access it from your controllers as needed. This way you would not need to pass it down to the next controller in the chain.

Comment: As per the answer above I would definitely recommend the singleton approach if you need to share data between multiple view controllers

Comment: Supposing that a singleton is not viable for my app, and speaking more broadly about apps in general, would there not be any memory leaks if each view controller that I pass data to has a strong pointer to it?  So if I'm just passing around data between view controllers it would be safe to have them all have strong pointers?

Comment: @JoeyFranklin Yes, it is safe to have strong pointers. The ARC will take care of releasing your `myPizzas` array as soon as the controller itself gets released; as soon as the reference count is zero, the object will get deallocated, preventing a memory leak.

Comment: He could go either way, but in practice, it's better to use strong everywhere except where you are trying to avoid retain cycles.  That way you don't have to keep track of which object has the strong reference and you don't have to ensure that it doesn't accidentally go away.

Comment: Also, avoid singletons where ever possible.

Comment: @JeremyP "avoid singletons where ever possible" Huh? I understand and support this statement in Java and C# ecosystems, but as far as models in Apple's ecosystem go, singletons appear to be quite mainstream. Is it not so? I'd love to read more on the subject of singletons in the objective c world, do you know a good link or two?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The principles of OO design apply equally to Objective-C as to Java - perhaps more so.  If nothing else, singletons make unit test implementation very difficult.